# Display process list in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to implement the below example in Django and list all process inside a table but I have hard times to display the information in the template. 
I ran this code in a python file and it's outputs multiple lists (one per process) as below

```
import psutil
for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'username', 'status', 'cpu_percent', 'memory_percent', 'memory_info', 'name']):
    process_info = [p.pid, p.info['username'], p.info['status'], p.info['memory_info'].rss, p.info['cpu_percent'], p.info['memory_percent'], p.info['name']]
    print(process_info)

[1, 'root', 'sleeping', 9142272, 0.0, 0.009034306321108227, 'systemd']
[2, 'root', 'sleeping', 0, 0.0, 0.0, 'kthreadd']
[3, 'root', 'idle', 0, 0.0, 0.0, 'rcu_gp']
[4, 'root', 'idle', 0, 0.0, 0.0, 'rcu_par_gp']
[5, 'root', 'idle', 0, 0.0, 0.0, 'kworker/0:0-events']
[6, 'root', 'idle', 0, 0.0, 0.0, 'kworker/0:0H-kblockd']
[8, 'root', 'idle', 0, 0.0, 0.0, 'mm_percpu_wq']
```

How can I process all these separate lists and display them as table rows ?

**Update**: Here is my request in views.py

```
def processes(request):
    for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'username', 'status', 'cpu_percent', 'memory_percent', 'memory_info', 'name']):
    process_info = [p.pid, p.info['username'], p.info['status'], p.info['memory_info'].rss, p.info['cpu_percent'], p.info['memory_percent'], p.info['name']]


    context_processes = {'process_info': process_info }
    return render(request, 'lwp_admin/processes.html', context_processes )
```

Below is the Django code in the template used for output:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-striped table-condensed">
                  <thead class="bg-green-gradient">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" class="col-xs-1 text-center">PID</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="col-xs-1 text-center">Owner</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="col-xs-1 text-center">Status</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="col-xs-1 text-center">RSS</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="col-xs-1 text-center">CPU usage (%)</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="col-xs-1 text-center">MEM usage (%)</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="col-xs-3 text-center">Command</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                      {% for proc in context_processes.process_info %}
                      <tr>
                          <td>{{ proc }}</td>
                      </tr>
                      {% endfor %}
                  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add your code where you tried to add that in template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK finally I managed to solve this:

**the views.py code is listed below**

```
def processes(request):
proc_objects = []
for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'username', 'cpu_percent', 'memory_percent', 'memory_info', 'name']):
    process_info = [p.pid, p.info['username'], round(p.info['memory_info'].rss), p.info['cpu_percent'],p.info['memory_percent'], p.info['name']]
    proc_objects.append(process_info)
    td_buttons = ['hangup', 'terminate', 'kill']

context_processes = {'proc_objects': proc_objects, 'td_buttons': td_buttons }
return render(request, 'lwp_admin/processes.html', context_processes)
```

**The template code is for this is listed below:**

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-striped table-condensed">
              <thead class="bg-maroon-gradient">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="col-xs-1 text-center">PID</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col-xs-1 text-center">Owner</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col-xs-1 text-center">RSS</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col-xs-1 text-center">CPU usage (%)</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col-xs-1 text-center">MEM usage (%)</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col-xs-3 text-center">Command</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="text-center">Hang Up</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="text-center">Terminate</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="text-center">Kill</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              {% for process_info in proc_objects %}
                  <tr class="text-center">
                      {% for proc in process_info %}
                          <td>{{ proc }}</td>
                      {% endfor %}
                      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Hang Up</button></td>
                      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Terminate</button></td>
                      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Kill</button></td>
                  </tr>
              {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
          </table>
```

The output for this is:
[[image: process list[1]]

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: based on new info**
You've already created a context dictionary and assigned it to `context_processes`. You don't pass a dictionary of a dictionary to `render()`.

Change your view code to:

`return render(request, 'lwp_admin/processes.html', context_processes )`

In your template you can loop through the passed context like this

```
<tr>
    {% for proc in process_info %}
        <td>{{ proc }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
```

---

For ref, may still be helpful on how to pass context to templates

Are you adding the dictionary you've generated into the view context? You can append to the context dictionary in your view method before passing it onto the template.

If your view is a function you just do so while building your context and pass it to the `render(request, template, context)` function. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/views/

If you are using class based views you can either, override or add `get_context_data()` method, depending on the base `View` class you are inheriting from. [see example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context)

In your template you can access the context values via the key you saved to it. e.g

```
{{ name }}
{{ pid }}
{{ username }}
```

see template docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/#variables
hope that helps